# Setting Priorities on Buttons

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how to set priorities on imagebutton.  I
want to have a layout with a bunch of Icon or buttons that can be
selected either by touch, radio, or checked box.  As these images are
selected they are set on queue to be displayed in order of
Precedence.
(that is to be pre-determined). The images are displayed once the
main
action button is touched.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below mentioned one in layout xml...

```
android:nextFocusDown=<id of the next control to be focussed>
android:nextFocusLeft=<id of the previous control to be focussed>
```

Or set the listeners for tab in java. such as,

```
if (<current control>.isFocused()) <next control>.requestFocus();
```